# How to obtain neighborhood from Canadian postal code

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api, reverse-geocoding, canada, postal-code

I want to group Canadian postal codes based on the neighborhood they belong to. I am currently using the google-maps-services API to convert postal codes into lat/long coords and grabbing the neighborhood from the response.

This is the function I wrote for it:

```
async function getGeoInfo(postalCode) {
    const response = await client.geocode({
        params: {
            address: postalCode,
            key: process.env.GMAPS_API_KEY
        }
    });
    const community = response.data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name
    const location = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    console.log("community: ", community)
    return {community, location};
}
```

This works for most postal codes but for some postal codes, it sends me the generic region instead of the neighborhood the postal code belongs to.

For example when running the above code on the postal code **T3A 0C9** the community becomes **Northwest Calgary** instead of the actual neighborhood which is **Varsity**

I have tried reverseGeocoding the lat/long coords and that returns a route component in the response object which in this case is **Varslea Place Northwest** but that makes it too specific as I only need the neighborhood the postal code belongs to.

It is my understanding that postal codes don't directly map to neighborhoods and they are used for postal delivery routes but is there any API/service that I can use to obtain the neighborhood or (closest neighborhood) that a particular postal code belongs to?

Comment: You might want to try again, Google is known for purposely returning bad/poor geocodes on a random percentage of the inputs, and the affected records are different between executions.

Comment: There was a reported issue with six figure Canadian Postcodes from Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227306320?pli=1 (Canada Post is the official source, they have tool/api for this at cost) https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/info/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/gettingstarted.jsf